# Android Development and testing on Device eats the phone internal hard disk space

Tags: java, android, eclipse, memory-management

I'm new to android development and right now I'm working on a game. However I was using the emulator first, which I found extremely slow (even though my PC is really good). So I started testing my app on my android device using the usb cable and the "debugging mode" set to "on". Later I got the error that my phone has almost run out of internal hard disk storage. first it was around 70 mb free and now its like 17mb..This is no good as now I would have to format my android phone to release the space... I dont know how Google can leave this bug in the first place..

Is there any other way to clear the invisible occupied space hogged by the app. I only tested the app on the phone. It wasnt Installed via market or manually.

My android phone is Samsung Galaxy Mini, and I was using eclipse for development

Comment: Settings -> Applications -> Manage Applications. Select yor app then use 'Clear data' and 'Clear cache'. BTW, if your app is 'eating' memory then it's because you are storing stuff which you're not clearing out correctly. This is not a bug in Android.

Answer (score 1):

Apps you installed through Eclipse are available to be removed through the normal way.  Go to Settings -> Applications -> Manage Applications (or whatever it is for your Android version) and select your app.  Within this screen, you can delete the app and you can also "Clear Data" and "Clear cache".  Clearing these items should free up that space.

That said, I have never heard of an app eating space just for fun.  Please make sure you don't have a leak of some sort.

Comment: Tried that before..didnt work... data and cache were only in kbs for that app...I had to format it which I did then